# PL/SQL Displaying Results

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have difficulty writing a PL/SQL Statement to display the following output.

These are my tables:

- Employee (E#, FName, LName,...)
- SkillPossessed (E#, SName, Level) (Employee may possessed more than 1 skills)

I need to display the output as follow:

```
1 Mary Loo:Sewing,Dancing,Cooking
2 Peter Pan:Painting, Singing
...
```

How do I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Comment: If I just use SQL Statement, I'm not able to display the output as above. The skills, Sewing, Dancing and Cooking are individual skills. Using SQL with Group by, it will be displayed only like the following: 1 Mary Loo Sewing, 1 Mary Loo Dancing, 1 Mary Loo Cooking (in separate line)

Comment: So why do you want PL/SQL code then? PL/SQL is only for stored procedures (and functions). You should also tell us which Oracle version you are using

Comment: I know I can use DBMS.output.put_line (E# || FName || LName || ':' || SName); But how to displayed more than one SName?

Answer (score 2):

No need for PL/SQL, just use LISTAGG.

```
create table employee (id number, fname varchar2(20), lname varchar2(20), primary key (id));
create table skillpossessed(employee_id number, sname varchar2(20), lvl number, constraint fk_employee_id foreign key(employee_id) references employee(id));
insert into employee values (1, 'Mary', 'Loo');
insert into employee values (2, 'Peter', 'Pan');
insert into skillpossessed values (1, 'Sewing', 1);
insert into skillpossessed values (1, 'Dancing', 2);
insert into skillpossessed values (1, 'Cooking', 5);
insert into skillpossessed values (2, 'Painting', 3);
insert into skillpossessed values (2, 'Singing', 1);

select e.id, e.fname, e.lname, listagg (s.sname, ',') 
within group (order by s.sname) as skills 
from employee e, skillpossessed s 
where e.id = s.employee_id group by e.id, e.fname, e.lname;

        ID FNAME  LNAME SKILLS
---------- ------ ----- ----------------------
         1 Mary   Loo   Cooking,Dancing,Sewing
         2 Peter  Pan   Painting,Singing
```

Comment: This is really useful. But if the question insists the use of PL/SQL, how could I do it? Thanks